kde - menu has no apps listed after upgrade to plasma 6.2
I work on debian testing. I ran a dist-upgrade this morning and rebooted so I could pick up all the things that have changed since my last reboot. I was greeted by a window telling me that I was working on Plasma 6.2... but menu is just empty, no apps show up. I have to start apps by hand by using alt+f2... So right now my launcher is konsole. I installed task-kde-desktop package and logged out/logged in again but it did not have any effect, menu is still empty. What can I do so that kde picks up all the stuff that is installed in my box?

This loaded a lot of stuff into the launcher, though I don't know if it's everything:
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications -v

Tip came from https://forum.manjaro.org/t/kde-launcher-no-longer-displays-hardly-any-installed-apps/148019/7
